# Excluding projects from code coverage using xUnit and coverlet

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, sonarqube, xunit

We are using Visual Studio 2022 and .Net 6.0.

We have create different test projects for each project added into the solution. And in each test project we have added xUnit and coverlet for unit test case writing and generating report.

We are writing a jenkins sonar build job to get the code coverage. This is working fine as of now but now we want exclude the projects from the code coverage and those should be displayed on sonar. So, this is how we are doing it as of now.

```
$SonarProjectKey = "<project key>"
Write-Host "------Sonar-Scanner Begin ------"
dotnet-sonarscanner begin /k:"<project key>" /n:"<project name>"  /d:sonar.verbose="true" /d:sonar.host.url="<sonar host ur>" /d:sonar.login="<sonar login id>"  /d:sonar.sourceEncoding="UTF-8" /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=".\coverage.opencover.xml"
Write-Host "------Sonar-Scanner Build ------"
dotnet build myproject.sln -o BuildArtifacts
dotnet test myproject.sln -o BuildArtifacts --no-build --no-restore -p:CollectCoverage=true -p:CoverletOutput=./TestResults/ -p:Exclude=\\\[.Tests]\\\ -p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover
Write-Host "------Sonar-Scanner Ends ------"
dotnet-sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login="<sonar login id>"
```

However, we have tried to exclude the project by using -p:Exclude and /d:sonar.exclusions as well, but still those projects are seen on sonarqube. Below are some of the commands we have tried.

```
dotnet test myproject.sln -o BuildArtifacts --no-build --no-restore -p:CollectCoverage=true /p:Exclude="[MyProject.Project.Infra.*]MyProject.Project.Infra" -p:CoverletOutput=./TestResults/ -p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover
```

Here above code statement, name of the project, namespace and dll is same. Still it is showing in sonarqube

So, the question how to exclude the projects which we dont want to show in sonarqube.
Also, our web api is having references of other projects. So, even if we try to exclude, those get compiled when web api project run.

Any help on this appreciated !